# Model structure into Laravel with this table structure?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

I am migrating old plain PHP RESTful API project into Lumen API Project. I am stuck on the structure of the Eloquent Model, responsible for fetching, inserting, updating or deleting data from database. I would like to know the structure and mapping of Model.

Here is some table structures:

```
stop {id, stop_name, stop_code, stop_status}

stop_detail {detail_id, stop_id, description, created_on, modified_on}

image {image_id, image_path, description, seq_order, is_thumb}

image_stop_mapping {stop_id, image_id, order}

place {place_id, place_title, description, place_status, order}

image_place_mapping {place_id, image_id, order}
```

Now, when I access the stop Model, I want to able to access the stop_detail, stop_images, stop_places, place_images in a single Model access. It should be like

```
public function findByStopId($stopId) {
    return Stop::where('id', $stopId)->with('stop_detail', 'stop_detail.stop_images', 'places', 'places.images')->get();
}
```

Can anyone help me to create the better structure of Eloquent Model?

Comment: you need to look more into model relationships etc like hasMany, hasOne, manyToMany, etc

Comment: have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships in order to properly define relationships in your Stop model, and then you'll be able to properly load them using `with()`/`load()` methods

Comment: did one of the answers help you?

Answer (score 1):

So for example within your Stop Model, you could have something like the following, but I am not sure about the actual relationships so bear with me.

```
  class Stop extends Model {

      public function stopdetails(){
          return $this->hasMany(StopDetails::class, 'stop_id');
     }

 }
```

Then call it something like:

```
 public function findByStopId($stopId) {
       return Stop::where('id', $stopId)->with('stopdetails')->get();
 }
```

Without knowing the total structure etc, but hope it helps you find or at least gives you a starter

Answer (score 0):

You want use "eager loading" (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), right?

So the method you wrote is perfectly fine - If the app knows the relations.

Basically you can guess them quite good (Since the one, who wrote it, used a simple naming convention.)

Just for an example: `image_stop_mapping {stop_id, image_id, order}` and `stop_detail {id, stop_id, description, created_on, modified_on}`

```
class Image extends Model 
{
   // ...
}

class ImageStopMapping extends Model
{
  public function image()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Image');
  }

  public function stop()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Stop');
  }
}

class Stop extends Model 
{
  public function stop_images()
  {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Image', 'App\ImageStopMapping');
  }

  public function details()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\StopDetail');
  }
}

class StopDetail extends Model 
{
  public function stop()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Stop');
  }
}
```

Didn't test it, but this should go in the right direction.